# Comparing elements of two different lists

Tags: r

I have two lists of parameters, one list contains the parameters value (`parameters` in the exemple below) and the other one contains all the enumerated values that each parameter can take (`parameters.enum`).

Parameters aren't mandatory so they can be `NULL`. All parameters aren't defined in `parameters.enum`, if the parameter is missing in `parameters.enum` then there is no restricted values for this parameter.

```
parameters.enum <- list(a = c("a1", "a2"),
                        b = c("b1", "b2"),
                        c = "c1")

parameters <- list(a = "a1", #allowed
                   b = "a1", #not allowed
                   c = NULL, #allowed
                   d = "aaa") #allowed
```

For each non `NULL` parameter in `parameter` and defined in `parameters.enum` I would like to check if they take a valid value. If not I would like to display a message, for exemple : `'b' should be one of "b1", "b2"`.

At the moment I use a loop to achieve what I want :

```
for (i in seq_along(parameters)) {
  j <- which(names(parameters.enum) == names(parameters[i]))
  if (length(j) != 0L && !is.null(parameters[[i]]) && !parameters[[i]] %in% parameters.enum[[j]]) {
    cat("Parameter \'", names(parameters[i]), "\' should be one of ", paste0("\"", parameters.enum[[j]], "\"", collapse = ", "), sep = "")
  }
}
```

But I feel like there could be a more straightforward and elegant way to achieve this, do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that loops over your parameters and uses `match.arg`. The result is a list that can be used for further processing:

```
results <- lapply(names(parameters), function(i) {
  if (!is.null(parameters.enum[[i]])) {
    try(match.arg(parameters[[i]], parameters.enum[[i]]))
  }
})
```